# Execute command at exact day of the week and time

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to change the status of my discord bot each day of the week, for example, change the status to "Playing" at 5 PM on Friday.

I have the status thing ready, but I don't know how to make the bot change it when the time comes.

Any ideas on how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

example

```
    import schedule
    import time
    
    def job():
        print("I'm working...")
    
    schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
    schedule.every().hour.do(job)
    schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

    schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
    schedule.every().monday.do(job)
    schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
    schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)
    
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron jobs to do this
In Ubuntu just write `crontab -e` and run your script command at the bottom of the file.